# When does iptable's conntrack module track states of packets?

Tags: linux, iptables, conntrack

It first needs to store states.  With some old BSD firewall that I used, I guess was named IPFW, I used to put a rule that sated "keep track of the state of the leaving packet", and this was placed on the outbound direction of interfaces.  Then, another rule on the inbound direction that checked them against those states that were created by the rule on the outbound direction.  So there used to be 2 rules:  (1) to populate the states table, this was on the outbound direction, and (2) to lookup the states table, this was on the inbound direction.

But with connntrack, I see it applied on the INPUT chain, such as this rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This makes me wonder, what is that statement actually doing?

- Is it saying that it will start tracking packets that match that rule by putting their information in the states table?
- Or is it saying that it already has the states information, and it is going to act against inbound messages based on it?  (e.g. accept if they belonged to a previously accepted connection?).  But, in this case, where did the states table get populated?  Which rule does it?  Or is it rule-less and implicit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Introductory presentation of Netfilter and conntrack

First the mandatory schematic about Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking:

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

Netfilter is the packet filtering framework inserting itself over the rest of the network stack (represented by "routing decision" and other white round-edged box parts). Netfilter provides hooks and APIs for other subsystems and "clients". Among these parts are *conntrack* (the connection tracker) and *iptables* (or *nftables*). The separation between Netfilter and *conntrack* is quite fuzzy. You can just consider *conntrack* as an integrated part of Netfilter.

In the schematic describing the various steps a packet traverses you can see that at some point (between raw/PREROUTING and mangle/PREROUTING, or between raw/OUTPUT and mangle/OUTPUT) the packet traverses *conntrack*.

At this point, *conntrack* will search in its own lookup tables (a mini lookup database kept in kernel memory):

- if this packet's charateristics are not found (and if not declared UNTRACKED in the raw table), a new conntrack bidirectional *tuple* entry (protocol, then specific family and protocol informations: initial source and port, initial destination and port, reply source and port, reply destination and port (those two last are usually the reverse, unless NAT or some strange protocols are involved, like echo reply matching echo request for ICMP)) describing the flow is created with state NEW.
- if it matches (in any direction) a previous entry and is compatible with this flow's state, the flow state might be altered (eg: changing from NEW to ESTABLISHED if that wasn't the case before).
- if for some specific reason the packet can't match an existing flow despite it having its characteristics (eg: a late TCP packet received after a retransmissions already kicked in successfully, so being out of window with regard to the sequence and SACK values) the packet will be tagged INVALID.
- there are a few other cases like RELATED: this is about packets not part of the flow itself but related to a new flow that can be associated with an other existing (ie: in the database) flow. Two examples are an ICMP error created from receiving a packet (eg: UDP port unreachable) or when a special protocol helper like the kernel module `nf_conntrack_ftp` , which is a plugin to the *conntrack* subsystem, detects that a packet is part of the separate data flow associated with the FTP commands PASV/EPSV or PORT/EPRT done on the command flow (on port 21).

---

### Addressing the question

All this being said, here are the answers to your two bullets:

- in the main network namespace *conntrack* starts tracking connections as soon as its modules (including possible relevant protocol-specific sub-modules) are loaded. For non-initial network namespaces (containers...) this also requires that some other subsystem references it (such as OP's *iptables*'s conntrack module or using once the command `conntrack` described later). This is the default and a packet must be specifically marked as UNTRACKED *before* the *conntrack* subsystem sees it for this packet to not be tracked. On Linux there are only a few cases where not tracking would be needed, but then of course stateful firewalling and stateful/dynamic NAT won't be available anymore (steless NAT which might even require to use UNTRACKED in the first place, can still be done, but not with *iptables*. *tc* or *nftables* can). To avoid *conntrack* handling some packets, this kind of *iptables* rule can be used (eg: port 80/tcp):

  ```
  iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j CT --notrack
  iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j CT --notrack
  ```
- When the packet traverses filter/INPUT and reaches this rule:

  > ```
  >  iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  > ```

  The *iptables*'s specific kernel module `xt_conntrack` queries the *conntrack* subsystem (handled by the various relevant kernel modules `nf_conntrack*`) and asks about the state of this packet in its lookup database. If the answer is `RELATED` or `ESTABLISHED` the packet matches and proceeds to the ACCEPT verdict. Actually the result is already [cached in](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L730) [the packet](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L645) the first time the lookup was done (usually by *conntrack*) so this is a cheap "lookup". This is thus a generic rule to handle flows already accepted before. Those flows can be initially  accepted in rules explicitly mentioning `-m conntrack --ctstate NEW` or simply rules not mentioning it but placed *after* this generic rule (but keep in mind the INVALID state, which should usually be DROPed before doing so).
- adding a bullet: the handling of incoming packets and outgoing packets is quite symmetrical between PREROUTING and OUTPUT (even if those don't look symmetrical): *conntrack* interfaces in PREROUTING as well as in OUTPUT (and in a few other places, considering *NAT* is working with *conntrack*, except for its first packet in state NEW traversing *iptables*'s nat table). This might be slightly different from the description you wrote about IPFW. If a server running applications is also restricting outgoing flows, then it most likely needs this same generic *iptables* rule both in filter/OUTPUT and in filter/INPUT, to allow outgoing reply packets of already accepted incoming traffic to pass.

---

### Additional informations

There are dedicated tools to interact with the *conntrack* subsystem's lookup tables from [conntrack-tools](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/).

- [`conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/conntrack.8): to query, delete or update the contents of the lookup tables handled by *conntrack*.

  Some examples.

  You can list all tracked entries (which can be big without additional filter) with:

  ```
  conntrack -L
  ```

  If your system is doing NAT (eg a router in front of a private LAN, or running VMs and containers) you can use `--any-nat`, `--src-nat` or `--dst-nat` to only display resp. all NAT, all source NAT (masquerade), or all destination NAT (typically for forwarded ports):

  Real-time monitoring of *conntrack* events:

  ```
  conntrack -E
  ```
- [`conntrackd`](https://manpages.debian.org/conntrackd.8): a daemon whose two main purposes are (conntrack) flow accounting and statistics, or [high-availability stateful firewall cluster](https://backreference.org/2013/04/03/firewall-ha-with-conntrackd-and-keepalived/) state synchronization.

Comment: Side question, is there always only one state? So that a packet cannot have a state of INVALID and ESTABLISHED at the same time. That there is no need to drop all INVALIDs at the top of the chain, but all other states can be processed first and INVALID last, before processing any non-state rules.

Comment: @kilves76  a packet without state is actually in INVALID state. It can't be ESTABLISHED at the same time. What matters about INVALID is that it's DROPed  and never REJECTed. If you REJECT any packet which missed the ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT rule, thinking there's nothing special to do about INVALID ones, you risk killing an innocent TCP connection when delayed packets are retried / duplicated, which could happen even hours after it was established. If your rules never REJECT, but use only DROP instead, then you can choose to not care about INVALID.

Answer (score 2):

Connection tracking is a separate function of Netfilter, and it is not configured with IPTables.

[image]

In the picture, there are two `conntrack` steps in INPUT path and one in OUTPUT path. These steps associate individual packets with existing connections tracked in the connection tracking table, or create new connection tracking entries in the table.

Conntrack functionality is a Linux kernel module, and it is often included in the kernel in default configuration.

Conntrack operation can be tuned by adjusting `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack` sysctl values.

Your second alternative is what happens. The state information is recorded by the Conntrack function, and the IPTables rule simply consults the Conntrack table for information.